# Make function available to google app script, from webpack module

Tags: webpack, google-apps-script

I am using webpack with gas-webpack-plugin to transpile my typescript code to JS so it can be used in code.gs(GAS main file). But when webpack modularize functions in the entry file, they are no longer available to Google App Script.

I tried to use gas-webpack-plugin to make the function available globally to GAS but no luck.
https://github.com/fossamagna/gas-webpack-plugin

here is my webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');
var GasPlugin = require('gas-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = env => {

return {
    context: __dirname,
    mode: 'production',
    entry: './main/Code.ts',
    optimization: {
        minimize: false
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'Code.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build/gs'),
    },
    plugins: [
        new GasPlugin()
    ]
};
```

};

i am exporting functions in my entry file like this

```
export function onOpen(){
    console.log('not working...');
}

export function testFunc(){
    console.log('not working...');
}
```

Comment: Have you tried clasp? It too allows you to use TypeScript with Google Apps Script.

Comment: A quick check of the source you link shows that multiple dependencies have been updated automatically since the last commit by the actual author. It's possible that those updates have altered some behavior. Otherwise I encourage you to review the actual README as it appears to cover how you should achieve the top level function exposure...

Comment: Thanks for your help @tehhowch, i didn't assign the function to global object, which was the problem in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To allow GAS-webpack-plugin to add top level declaration of functions, we have to assign functions to Node.js global object like this. which was missing. so my Entry file becomes

from

```
export function onOpen(){
    console.log('not working...');
}

export function testFunc(){
    console.log('not working...');
}
```

to

```
function onOpen(){
    console.log('not working...');
}

export function testFunc(){
    console.log('not working...');
}

global.onOpen = onOpen;
global.testFunc= testFunc;
```